# Finding elements from list in lists embedded in list (Python)

Tags: python, list

Is there any simple function to iterate through lists embedded in a list in Python? I have a list

`A = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`.

Then, I want check which elements could be found in list of lists

`B = [["banana", "cherry", "pear"], ["banana"," orange']]`.

The result should be sth like this: `c = [["banana", "cherry"], ["banana"]]`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any thing you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```py
[
   [ b
     for b in l # loop over items in the sub list
     if b in A] # Check in they are in the main list
   for l in B # Loop over the big list
]
```

This will maintain correct order, and also preserve empty lists

Comment: Very neat. Considering the given testcase is small, there is another possibility. `C = [ [ a for a in A if a in l] for l in B ]`.

Comment: Yep that would follow the order of items in A instead of the order in B

Comment: Interesting,. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over list B and do a set intersection and retain results if there is a match. Note that set will disrupt the order of items.

```
C = []
for item in B:
    common = set(item).intersection(A)
    if len(common) > 0:
        C.append(list(common))

print(C) # [['banana', 'cherry'], ['banana']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteration in given lists A & B doable sth like this;

```
A = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

B = [["banana", "cherry", "pear"], ["banana","orange"]]

C = []
for i in B:
    C_temp = []
    for j in A:
        if j in i:
            C_temp.append(j)
    C.append(C_temp)
print(C)
```

Output of C;

```
[['banana', 'cherry'], ['banana']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is using `map`, `lambda`, `set`, and `list` function  to iterate through lists:

```
A = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
B = [["banana", "cherry", "pear"], ["banana",'orange']]
C = list(map(lambda c: sorted(list(set(A).intersection(c))), B))

# [['banana', 'cherry'], ['banana']]
```